# Ruby - rails - split string & print in reverse order

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to split a string and print it beginning from bottom on my views. The standard way starts reading string from the beginning and prints accordingly. How do I reverse it?

```
<% @a[:log].to_s.split(/----/).each do |line| %>
<div width='100%'><pre class="log"><%= "#{line}" %></pre></div>
<% end %>


@a[:log] is a string something like this: One ---- Two ---- Three ---- Four

I want this printed reverse starting from Four, instead of One. 

<div width='100%'><pre class="log">Four</pre></div>
<div width='100%'><pre class="log">Three</pre></div>
<div width='100%'><pre class="log">Two</pre></div>
<div width='100%'><pre class="log">One</pre></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
@a[:log].to_s.split(/----/).each
```

Do:

```
@a[:log].to_s.split(/----/).reverse.each
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want an intermediate array (which the `reverse` method returns), then there is `reverse_each`.

```
@a[:log].to_s.split(/----/).reverse_each
```

Answer (score 1):

`@a[:log].to_s.split(/----/).reverse.each`